# return data which value is not empty or exists in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, python-3.x

i am a beginner in python and mongodb. My database is like this

```
{ '_id' : 1,
  'identity' : { 
          'first_name' : 'John',
          'last_name' : 'Doe',
          'phone' : '+440823XXX'
         }
   'status' : 'active'
}
```

I want to return data which phone is empty or doesn't exists in db. I tried

```
db.collection.find({"identity" : { "phone" : { "$exists": "true", "$ne": "null" }  }})
```

But it returned `<pymongo.cursor.Cursor at 0x7f5da40e8e80>`

How the sintax for getting the query which the value is not empty?

Comment: Try : `db.collection.find({"identity"."phone" : { "$exists": "true", "$ne": "null" }  }})`

Comment: @Nikhil Fadnis , It said "syntax invalid " on "identity"."phone"

Comment: @Diyah, check `db.collection.find({"identity.phone"  { $exists: "true", $ne: "null" }  })`

Comment: Your correction is working, unfortunately it just return <pymongo.cursor.Cursor at 0x7f5da40f6fd0>. what I want here is to return the data

Comment: @Diyah, I have updated the answer, please take a look on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this code :

```
db.collection.find({"identity.phone" { $exists: "true", $ne: "null" } })
```

It will return a cursor, so

```
cur = db.collection.find({"identity.phone" { $exists: "true", $ne: "null" } })
```

and you got the data in `cur`. just loop through it.

```
for doc in cur:
...
```

For further reference check [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.4/reference/operator/query/exists/)

Comment: Thank you very much @Kiran ML. this code:  "for doc in cur" that i need. This is because of my misunderstanding.